AWS CloudWatch Logs Insights - Query editor - Inconsistencies
I have noticed some inconsistencies when writing queries to search my logs, specially when writing parsers. I wonder if this is a defect withing the editor or if I am doing something wrong, which I would appreciate is someone can tell me what is wrong. I has to do with the use of single and double quotes
For instance, look at this query...
field @timestamp
| filter @message like /labels/
| parse @message "label1" as label1

This works just fine, I get a table of timestamp and values for field label1.
Now I add one more parser as follows...
field @timestamp
| filter @message like /labels/
| parse @message "label1" as label1
| parse @message "label2" as label2

But this fails. I get a 'token recognition error'.
The only way I managed to solve the problem is by changing the double quote on the first parser to single quote, but only on the first parser. The second parser needs to stay with double quote, it won't work otherwise. Resulting on this query...
field @timestamp
| filter @message like /labels/
| parse @message 'label1' as label1
| parse @message "label2" as label2

What am I doing wrong?
I must say that the examples above are simplifications to facilitate the explanations. Below one of my logs and the query I created for it...
{"time":"2024-04-01T11:06:51.101231139Z","log":"time=\"2024-04-01T11:06:51Z\" level=info msg=\"{\\\"labels\\\":[{\\\"label1\\\":0.1,\\\"type\\\":\\\"type1\\\"}],\\\"context\\\":{\\\"dataHolder\\\":{\\\"IP_ADDRESS\\\":\\\"10.10.10.45\\\",\\\"number5g\\\":\\\"e56c233332b84c5b888807ae2fefecef\\\",\\\"xrep\\\":\\\"10.26768405538058,-10.43256639391846,9.883302853282586\\\"},\\\"number\\\":2,\\\"number2\\\":\\\"006611\\\",\\\"number3\\\":1,\\\"number4\\\":\\\"4d34e560\\\",\\\"number5\\\":\\\"11\\\"},\\\"number6\\\":\\\"1\\\",\\\"number7\\\":\\\"3\\\"}\"}

And query...
fields @timestamp
| filter @message like /IP_ADDRESS/
| parse @message 'label1\\\\\\":*,\\\\\\"type\\\\\\":\\\\\\*\\\\\\' as label1, type
| parse @message "\\\\\\"IP_ADDRESS\\\\\\":\\\\\\"*\\\\\\",\\\\\\"number5g\\\\\\":\\\\\\"*\\\\\\",\\\\\\"xrep\\\\\\":\\\\\\"*\\\\\\" as IPAddress, number5g, xrep
| limit 10

